# Is my understanding of random variable and pmf correct?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am trying to figure out if I've got it down correctly. (Sorry it's so small,  you can click on the picture to enlarge it)

[image]

**EDIT:** About the notation: A random experiment is performed and the set of possible outcomes is $S = \{s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5 \}$. The random variable is an injective function $X: S \to \mathbb{R}$. The pmf is a not necesarily injective function $f: \text {range} (X) \to (0, 1)$.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe in words what you mean.  In general, if $S$ is a discrete probability space and $X: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable, then the $P(X = x) = \sum_{\{s \in S |X(s) = x \} } p(s)$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Sorry, I just added more details to the OP.

Comment: @JairTaylor So I gather $X$ does not necesarily have to be injective?

Comment: No, $X$ need not be injective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was also asked in [Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/282391)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right.  You have

- $S$, a sample space: a set of all possible outcomes.
- $X$, a random variable: a map of $S\mapsto \Bbb R$.  A map from the sample space *to* a measure space, in this case the real numbers.

  - $X$ is not necessarily injective: several distinct outcomes *may* map to the same measure.
- $f$, a function mapping the reals to the interval $(0;1)$, with the other required properties of *probability mass function*.

  - Indeed, also not necessarily injective.
  - The function has an evaluation of zero at all points excluding the image of $X$ from $S$, called the support of $f$.

Take an example the sample space $S=\{s_1,s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5\}$.

We may for example have a random variable $X(s) = \begin{cases}X_1&:& s\in\{s_1,s_5\}\\ X_2&:& s=s_2\\ X_3&:& s=s_3\\ X_4&:& s=s_4\end{cases}$

Then $f(X_1) = \Bbb P(\{s_1, s_5\})$, $f(X_2)=\Bbb P(\{s_2\})$, and so forth, with $f(X_1)+f(X_2)+f(X_3)+f(X_4)=1$ .